# jquery toggleClass to just children element

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child, children, toggleclass

i have an issue to toggleclass for just children element.

```
<ul class="sample-menu">
<li id="sample-topmenu_2">
    <a href="#" class="sample-icon">Menu Text</a>
    <ul class="sample-submenu">
        <li class="submenu"><a href="#" class="sample-icon">Submenu Text</a></li>
        <li class="submenu"><a href="#" class="sample-icon">Submenu Text</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="sample-topmenu_3">
    <a href="#" class="sample-icon">Menu Text2</a>
    <ul class="sample-submenu">
        <li class="submenu"><a href="#" class="sample-icon">Submenu Text2</a></li>
        <li class="submenu"><a href="#" class="sample-icon">Submenu Text2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

i use this jquery toggle, but it's toggle all li elements for all menu.

```
$( "*[id^=bga-topmenu_] p" ).click(function() {
  $("li.submenu").toggleClass( "sumenu_show" );
});
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: That it a super weird selector.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
$( "*[id^=bga-topmenu_]" ).click(function() {
  $(this).find("li.submenu").toggleClass( "sumenu_show" );
});
```

You can use `$(this)` to get the current context (i.e. the clicked element) and then find all `<li>` elements with the submenu `class` within that context, using the `.find()` method.

Comment: I just removed the "P" and it's work. thanks a ton man...

$( "*[id^=bga-topmenu_] " ).click(function()

Comment: Please add me a + reputation, Thanks